# Magento2.3.2: Path "app/etc/" cannot be used with directory "/app/etc/"

Tags: cache, admin-panel, magento2.3.2

I am working on Magento2.3.2

When I tried to enable cache types from the admin panel, I am getting the following error.

```
Path "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/etc/" cannot be used with directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/etc/"
```

I am not seeing any log also.

I tried changing all permissions by using the following commands

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After I used to run above commands, I am getting the following Fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir
>   "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/page_cache" is not writable in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180):
>   Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/opt...') #1
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87):
>   Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/opt/bitnami/ap...') #2
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153):
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156):
>   Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...',
>   Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /opt/bit in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php
>   on line 209

Comment: Did you check the directory permissions?

Comment: @Sukeshini, i updated description

Comment: you have not assigned proper permission to magento set up. for var directory , chmod -R 777 var/cache/* var/page_cache/*

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang, I just updated the permissions, check once, website is not opening

Answer (score 0):

You need to give ownership permission to your apache user in magento directory.